# jQuery Error: Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am not sure why jquery is giving me error in my express app. I belive I am using the full version of jquery.

this is my code in my js file.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log('Jquery Working');
  $('.card').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked')
  })
  $.get('/quizes', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

And this is how I am connecting to jQuery

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one jQuery installed

Comment: Do you use bootstrap? They can include the slim version of jQuery and cause a conflict.

Comment: Yes I am using Bootstrap. So how do I resolve this conflict, because I have to use bootstrap.

Comment: Inspect and see if there is a .slim and remove it

Comment: you guys are terrific to be honest. actually bootstrap was using the slim version which was causing the issue. If you hadnt mention this i would have been lost.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Bootstrap was using the slim version of jQuery which was causing the conflict.